# delete all the existing entries before inserting new entries in cakephp 3 for the same data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp-3.0

This is my controller =>

When I use deleteAll() I get this error =>
Error: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

When I use delete() I get this error =>
Error: unknown method isnew

```
    public function addSolution($ids = null)
{
    $user_id=$this->Auth->User('id');
    $city_id=$this->Auth->User('city_id'); 
    $location_id=$this->Auth->User('location_id'); 
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('super_admin_layout');
    $id = $this->EncryptingDecrypting->decryptData($ids);
    $customerProblem = $this->CustomerProblems->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    $cust_id = $customerProblem['customer_id'];
    $order_no = $customerProblem['order_no'];
    
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $customerProblem = $this->CustomerProblems->patchEntity($customerProblem, $this->request->getData());
        $search=$this->request->getData();
        $solutions=$this->request->getData()['solution'];
        $delete = $this->CustomerProblems->find()->where([
            'customer_id' => $search['customer_id'],
            'mobile_no' => $search['mobile_no'],
            'order_no' => $search['order_no'],
            'problem' => $search['problem'],
            'resolve_status' => $search['resolve_status'],
            'status' => $search['status']
        ]);
        if($this->CustomerProblems->deleteAll($delete)){
            foreach ($solutions as $solution) {
                $customerProblem = $this->CustomerProblems->newEntity();
                $customerProblem->city_id = $city_id;
                $customerProblem->created_by = $user_id;
                $customerProblem->customer_id = $this->request->getData()['customer_id'];
                $customerProblem->mobile_no = $this->request->getData()['mobile_no'];
                $customerProblem->order_no = $this->request->getData()['order_no'];
                $customerProblem->problem = $this->request->getData()['problem'];
                $customerProblem->resolve_status = $this->request->getData()['resolve_status'];
                $customerProblem->status = $this->request->getData()['status'];
                $customerProblem->solution = $solution;
                $this->CustomerProblems->save($customerProblem);
            }
            $this->Flash->success(__('The customer problem has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The customer problem could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $customers=$this->CustomerProblems->Customers->find()->where(['Customers.id'=>$cust_id,'Customers.status'=>'Active']);
    $customer=[];
    foreach($customers as $data1){
        $customer[]= ['value'=>$data1->id,'text'=>ucwords($data1->name)." (".$data1->username.")"];
    }
    $getAllSolution = $this->CustomerProblems->find()->where(['CustomerProblems.order_no'=>$order_no,'CustomerProblems.status'=>'Active'])->extract('solution');
    $this->set(compact('customerProblem','customer','getAllSolution'));
}
```

Comment: what does this show: `echo $this->CustomerProblems->find()->where($delete)->sql();`

Answer (score 0):

```
        $delete = $this->CustomerProblems->find()->where([
            'customer_id' => $search['customer_id'],
            'mobile_no' => $search['mobile_no'],
            'order_no' => $search['order_no'],
            'problem' => $search['problem'],
            'resolve_status' => $search['resolve_status'],
            'status' => $search['status']
        ]);
        $flag = 0;
        // pr($delete->toArray());die;
        foreach ($delete as $key) {
            $this->CustomerProblems->delete($key);
            $flag = 1;
        }
        if($flag == 1){
            foreach ($solutions as $solution) {
                $customerProblem = $this->CustomerProblems->newEntity();
                $customerProblem->city_id = $city_id;
                $customerProblem->created_by = $user_id;
                $customerProblem->customer_id = $this->request->getData()['customer_id'];
                $customerProblem->mobile_no = $this->request->getData()['mobile_no'];
                $customerProblem->order_no = $this->request->getData()['order_no'];
                $customerProblem->problem = $this->request->getData()['problem'];
                $customerProblem->resolve_status = $this->request->getData()['resolve_status'];
                $customerProblem->status = $this->request->getData()['status'];
                $customerProblem->solution = $solution;
                $this->CustomerProblems->save($customerProblem);
            }
            $this->Flash->success(__('The customer problem has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The customer problem could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`deleteAll` does not take a list of entities to delete, it takes an array of conditions and deletes everything that matches.

```
if($this->CustomerProblems->deleteAll([
    'customer_id' => $search['customer_id'],
    'mobile_no' => $search['mobile_no'],
    'order_no' => $search['order_no'],
    'problem' => $search['problem'],
    'resolve_status' => $search['resolve_status'],
    'status' => $search['status']
])) {
```

Note that it returns the number of rows affected, not true/false, so your `if` logic might need to change somewhat to take that into account.